# Localization commutes with tensor products

Tags: algebraic-geometry, localization

I'm trying to prove that localization commutes with tensor products (Dummit and Foote. Abstract algebra, Sec 15.4 Ex 16). There is a unique isomorphism of $D^{-1}R$-modules

$$\varphi: D^{-1}M\otimes_{D^{-1}R}(D^{-1}N)\cong D^{-1}(M\otimes_{R}N)$$

with $\varphi(\frac{m}{d}\otimes \frac{n}{d'})$ given by $\frac{m\otimes n}{dd'}$ for any $R$-modules $M,N$, and multiplicatively closed set $D$ in $R$. {I think I have managed to prove the existence of isomorpism as follows: $$(D^{-1}M)\otimes_{D^{-1}R}(D^{-1}N)\cong(D^{-1}R\otimes_{R}M)\otimes_{D^{-1}R}(D^{-1}R\otimes_RN)\\$$ $$\cong D^{-1}R\otimes_R(M\otimes_{D^{-1}R}D^{-1}R)\otimes_{R}N\cong D^{-1}R\otimes_{R}M\otimes_{R}N\cong D^{-1}(M\otimes_{R}N)$$

However, I am stuck in uniqueness part. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, if you show that such $\phi$ exists then by definition it is unique as it verify $\phi(m/d \otimes n/d') = (m \otimes n)/dd'$.

Comment: $\text {>>Chikenmancer Thank you for noticing. According to your advise, I rewrote my question}\\$ $\text {>>N.H., thanks for quick reply. First, I'm not sure}$ $\phi$ $\text {is an isomorphism.}\\$ Considering bilinear map from $D^{-1}M \times D^{-1}N$ $\:$ to $D^{-1}(M\otimes_{R}N)$, $\:$$\text {I could see $\phi$ is surjective homomorophism.}\\$ $\: \text {However, I could not prove that }$ $\phi$ is injective. $\text {Second, even if I could prove that}$ $\phi$ $\text {is injective, I have no idea how to show the uniqueness....Could you help me?} $

Comment: Hint: Show that $D^{-1}M=M \otimes_{R} D^{-1} R$ and then show that taking tensor products commutes.

Comment: $\text {>>user45878 Thank you very much for nice hint!}\\ \text {Thanks to your advice, I successfully find well-defined inverse}\\ (m\otimes n)/d \to (m/1)\otimes(n/d)\\ \text {And, I find a mistake in above chain of isomorphism. Thank you so much!!}$

Comment: This comment is a bit late, but I am wary of your second step: the $R$-module $M$ does not *a priori* admit a $D^{-1} R$-module structure, so the associative property might fail for $(D^{-1} R \otimes_R M) \otimes_{D^{-1} R} D^{-1} R.$ On the other hand, there is a way to make an argument like this: because $D^{-1} R$ is both an $R$-module and a $D^{-1} R$-module, the associative property holds for $(D^{-1} M \otimes_{D^{-1} R} D^{-1} R) \otimes_R N.$