# Flatness of Residue Field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question refers to a step of in the proof of Corollary 8.5.17 in  Bosch's "Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry";  see page 395

See the red tagged line below:

[image]

We consider the exact sequence

$$0 \to I/J \to R[t_1, ..., t_n]/J \to R[t_1, ..., t_n]/I \to 0$$

and we tensor it with $k(s) = \mathcal{O}_{S,s}/m_s$.

Why does it stay exact? Indeed, by assumption $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ is flat so it's ok to tensor it with $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ but what about $k(s)$? Why does it conserve the exactness?

In addition: Lemma 5.2.9:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the assumption $R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]/I$ flat over $R$? Then, tensoring over $R$ with $k(s)=R/M$, $M$ a maximal ideal, stays exact. Easiest way is to say that the kernel on the left is $Tor^1_R(k(s), R[t_1,\ldots.t_n]/I)=0$ by flatness.

Comment: @Mohan: I'm not sure why $R$ should be flat over $R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]/I$. Well, firstly we can indeed assume $S= Spec(R)$ and $X= Spec(R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]/I)$ since problem is local. The assumption (ii) says that $f$ is only flat in $x$ not everywhere, so we know that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$, right? I don't see why flatness is inherited for $R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]/I$ over $R$. Please, correct me if I have overseen some argument.

Comment: What does 5.2/9 say?

Comment: @Ben: I added it above. So the the core problem stays to see why $R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]/I$ is flat over $R$ althought we only know that $f$ is flat in $x$.

Comment: Localize the sequence at $m_x$, which is still exact (localization is exact). Then by assumption the third term is flat over $R_s$, so apply 5.2/9 to the module $k(s) = R_s/m_s$. Does that do it?

Comment: By the way, the statement "by assumption $\mathcal O_{S,s}$ is flat” I don't think is right. From what I can tell, in this question $S$ is over an arbitrary base $Spec\ \mathbb Z$ so there is no assumption it's flat! (For instance if $S$ is spectrum of a finite field.) I think the assumption should be that $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a flat $\mathcal O_{S,s}$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $T = R[t_1,\ldots, t_n]$. Our assumption that $f$ is flat at $x$ means that $(T/I)_x$ is flat over $R_s$.

We have an exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to I/J \to T/J \to T/I \to 0$$
Localization is exact so we again have the localized exact sequence:
$$0 \to (I/J)_x \to (T/J)_x \to (T/I)_x \to 0$$
Now in 5.2/9, we take $M''$ to be $(T/I)_x$ since it is flat over $R_s$, and take $N$ to be $k(s) = R_s/m_s$. We get the exact sequence we wanted:
$$0 \to (I/J)_x\otimes k(s) \to (T/J)_x\otimes k(s) \to (T/I)_x\otimes k(s) \to 0$$
This justifies the statement "[the sequence] remains exact at $x$ when tensoring over $R$ it with $k(s)$".

(Sweeping it under the rug, but we just used that [Localization commutes with tensor products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292960/localization-commutes-with-tensor-products) to identify $M\otimes_{R_s} k(s) = M\otimes_{R}k(s)$ for an $R_s$-module $M$ by the way.)

Watch out for the typo in the next line though, $J/I$ should be $I/J$.

---

Per the title of this question: The residue field $k(s)$ is not going to be a flat module, see e.g. [is residue field ever flat over its local ring?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66792/is-residue-field-ever-flat-over-its-local-ring) on MathOverflow, so it's important that $N$ in 5.2/9 can be any module.